# Why are the symbols of the markings on the ground given differently on two different charts of the same AIP?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, ground-operations, airport-markings, symbology

Why are the symbols of the signs on the ground given differently on two different charts of the same AIP? As can be seen in the images below, the ground markings in the same region on the airport chart and parking chart are different. Runway/Runway Approach Holding Position Marking, which includes 2 straight and 2 dash lines, is used on the Airport chart. On the Parking chart, Non-Movement Area Boundary Marking, which includes 1 flat and 1 dash line, is used. Why are different sign symbols used and how can I find out what the real signs are used on the airport surface?

Names of airport chart and parking chart in TURKEY AIP, respectively:
"AD 2 LTAF ADC" and "AD 2 LTAF PRKG-1"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't figure out what you wanted me to check.

Comment: There is 1 year between the publication and effective date of the charts, and there has been no such change during this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either symbol is appropriate:

[image]

It's hard to know why two depictions of the same thing are shown differently, I suspect it has something to do differing departments/processes used to create the content. Furthermore, the decision of which symbol to use may have changed over time: The airport chart is dated 05/20 whereas the parking chart is dated 11/22.

As for knowing what the *real* thing actually looks like, you could always use [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/36%C2%B058%2755.0%22N+35%C2%B016%2749.0%22E/@36.9882184,35.2902094,1068m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d36.981944!4d35.280278?hl=en&entry=ttu)

[image]

Looks like 1 solid and 1 dashed line.

Comment: --Thanks a lot!